# How can I teach myself websphere?

Tags: websphere

I have a chance to learn how to administer and develop for WebSphere.  But after trying to find a book for it I am at a loss where to begin.  I was hoping for some advice.  I may have access to the IBM RAD IDE (I think that's what it is), but I am not sure.

I have a project I'd like to put on it but I am lost.  Thanks.

edit:  I do not care which language I end up using.

Comment: Websphere is really broad? Websphere is an application server, but it depends exactly what you want to accomplish with this. It's close to saying you want to learn Windows? Depending on your needs would depend on the advice you get. You'll also most likely end up using Java if you're creating and deploying J2EE applications on it.

Comment: @ferrari fan - thanks.  Would it be more like learning IIS since that is close to the same for Windows?

Comment: It depends, for example I am in a project that uses Websphere Portal Server(WPS) which runs as part of Websphere Application Server (WAS). In my particular instance I am basically developing for WPS in RAD using JSP's and such. This is what I mean, besides starting my server (WAS) with WPS running, I'm not literally working with WAS. So you could say I really develop for WPS instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. There are two parts to your question (and I'm sticking to the base application server here):

a) writing applications: WebSphere Application Server is a J2EE application server. So any web resource or forum or blog describing how to write servlets or JSPs or applications that use EJBs will work. There are lots of those. If you want to stick with IBM resources, you could look for redbooks or developerworks articles. For more general information (patterns, practices, etc) you could try http://theserverside.com.

b) administering the application server: Redbooks like [this](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247615.html?Open) can give a pretty good overview (as the other poster mentioned).

There is also a [WebSphere education channel on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/WebSphereEducation) which addresses both questions.

Answer (score 2):

Download a trial MQ server from IBM (*to some hosts or VMs? that won't matter if you break them...*), and (optionally) add a WMB in front of it to transform some messages and fire some messages at it from a GUI client via another broker?

so you 'could':
ia92 java gui to fire messages->microbroker(or rsmb or mosquitto)->WMB(optional)->MQ

have a look at the messages arriving on MQ via Websphere explorer (or its command line client, try googling for 'websphere MQ quick reference card') have a fiddle about with its subscriptions etc

and then start consuming those messages from its queues on the 'other' side of the chain via a WAS and then a java client
MQ->MQ(bridge maybe)->WAS->some Java EE client you've written

don't forget the red books, keep it simple and then keep on adding complexity e.g. encryption etc.

Comment: my above 'answer' was a bit 'download some stuff and have a play', if you just want to have an inspect of your setup you could do worse than getting Websphere explorer downloaded to your pc and then having a look at your current system, there's also the command line client, start from 'dspmq' (on the cheat sheet) and work on from there